# ¿Como puedo utilizar la variable (local) que se encuentra dentro de una clase fuera de la clase (global)?

Tags: python

soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación. Me pueden ayudar a entender como puedo usar una variable de instancia de forma global. En este caso quisiera usar las variables self.x y self.y por fuera de la clase. Gracias !!!

```
    import tkinter as tk
    import win32gui
    from PIL import ImageGrab

    class TestApp:
        def __init__(self, master):
            frame = tk.Frame(master)
            frame.pack()

            self.master = master

            b1 = tk.Button(text='ok', command=self.pressed)
            b1.pack()

        def pressed(self):
            self.x = ventana.winfo_x()+7
            self.y = ventana.winfo_y()+30
            print('tkinter location: ({},{})'.format(self.x, self.y))

    ventana = tk.Tk()
    ventana.title("Palynology")
    ventana.geometry('300x300')
    ventana.configure(background='blue')
    ventana.attributes('-alpha', 0.5)
    app = TestApp(ventana)
    ventana.mainloop()

    #img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x,y,x+300,y+300)) #x1, y1, x2, y2
    #img.show()
```

Comment: Puedes acceder a los atributos de la instancia con `app.x` y `app.y` (deberias inicializar ambos en el `__init__` a `None` y despues comprobar que estos no sigan siendo `None` una vez cerrada la ventana (no se pulsó el botón)) pero no tengo muy claro que pretendes hacer.... `ventana.mainloop()` es bloqueante, si quieres que la captura solo se muestre cuando se cierra la ventana de tkinter con lo anterior basta pero si quieres que la captura se muestre al pulsar el botón ok entonces no. ¿Podrías aclarar esto?

Comment: Muchas Gracias FJSevilla !!!

Comment: Sí funciona !!! Lo que intento hacer es capturar una zona especifica de la pantalla lo cual lo define la pocision de la ventana y con el boton "ok" defino la coordenada superior izquierda en donde esta ubicada dicha ventana.

Comment: Mil Gracias FJSevilla !!!